# Capybara, using expect inside within

Tags: selenium, testing, cucumber, capybara

I am working with Capybara right now and I have a issue I was not able to resolve:
I am logging into a page and I want to check, whether the login was successful. So I have the following code:

```
    within(:id,'user_dropdown') do
        expect(find('.name')).to have_content 'test'
    end
```

But with doing this, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `expect' for #<Object:0x007fc39328ab78>
```

I think it has something to do, that expect is not available in the scope inside within. But how can I do this else?

Already thank you!

Comment: Upgrade: It seems like expect isn´t found at all. But other methods of capybara like visit are available. Anyone might know why?
Means:          
within(:id,'user_dropdown') do
           element = find('.name')
 end
 expect(page).to have_content 'test'
Doesn't work either

Comment: `expect` isn’t a Capybara method, it’s an `RSpec` method. Are you actually using RSpec with Cucumber, or are you using something else (Minitest perhaps)?

Comment: Yes thank you, that was the problem. I added **rspec-expectations** to my gemfile, now it works. I will keep this here, in case someone has the same issue.